# how to create directory in internal memory programmatically in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I have Googled a lot and tried every code that I can get but cant seem to create a directory on my NEXUS 4 device. Can please someone help me. Thanks

This is the work I did already:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static String TAG="YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME";
private String filename = "MySampleFile.txt";
private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
File myInternalFile;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

  String FILE_NAME = "MyMusic.mp3";
  File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  File file = new File(path, FILE_NAME);
   path.mkdirs();

}
```

Comment: @thepersonWhoDoesn'tReadsCarfully. This is the reason i said i am new to android programming and "internal memory" no SD cards in Nexus 4 device

Comment: Your question may be mis-titled.  "Internal memory" usually refers to the app-private storage location from Context.getFilesDirectory() but the Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() call you are using refers to external storage which may (depending on device) *either* be permanently installed *or* removable **and requires external storage permission in your manifest**.  Additionally, on many newer devices external storage changes are not visible until the media scanner is invoked.

Comment: i also tried "This question may already have an answer here:" link. wont work

Comment: "won't work" is not a problem report anyone can help you with.

Comment: Like after installing Watsapp. it make a folder Named WATSAPP. i want that which i couldnt get any help of.

Comment: You are going to have to report **exactly** what you tried and exactly **how you determined that it failed**, if you want any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`File.mkDirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) method. For example:

```
File sub = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "subdirectory");
if (!sub.exists())
    sub.mkdirs();
```

Comment: I already did. @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

  String FILE_NAME = "MyMusic.mp3";
  File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  File file = new File(path, FILE_NAME);
   path.mkdirs();

}